# Funky Character getting generated with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, character

For some reason this character is getting generated in my HTML email when it is being sent: â€“. I have tried replacing it with nothing in my PHP using preg_replace('/â€“/', '', $var), but that is not working. For some reason when I get an email containing HTML this character shows up. I am guessing it is generated from this JavaScript in my code somehow:

```
$('.comments0').click(function(){
    $('.comments').val($('.comments').val() + 'Our warranties are:\nNew – 1 year\nRemanufactured - 6 months\nRepair - 6 months');
});
```

If it is not being generated with JavaScript, I am not sure how this character keeps getting created in the middle of my HTML. It gets generated right after New, just like this: New â€“ 1 Year. I have no idea why this character is coming up randomly like this.

By the way, here is the HTML directly related to that JavaScript:

```
<form action="?AddToQuote" method="POST" id="myForm" name="myForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="comments[0]" class="comments0" id="comments0" /><label>6 Months Warranty</label>
<textarea cols="75" rows="6" name="comments" class="comments" id="comments"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['comments'])) { echo $_SESSION['comments']; } ?></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you verify that characters after New are space and dash and not some unicode counterparts?

Comment: What do you mean by "unicode counterparts"?

Comment: Can you delete characters *New - 1* and manually retype them again and see if the issue persists?

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for the help! :D Too bad you didn't use this as an answer, or I would +1 your reply and select it as correct answer.

Comment: I can still post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the characters in your message were copied/pasted from somewhere else. If you delete them and manually retype directly in the JS source that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks again, that worked perfectly! I guess I did not realize I had copied and pasted the text.

Answer (score 1):

This is an en dash:

> New **–** 1 year

If you don’t serve the script with the same encoding as it was written in, there will be errors. So make sure it’s saved as UTF-8 and serve it as UTF-8. If the JavaScript is part of your HTML, add this at the top of the `<head>` (HTML5):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

You can test it:

```
$ echo '–' > test.html
$ firefox test.html
(â€“ shows up in a browser)
```

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: @Tigerman55: Is the JavaScript in a `<script>` element, or a different file?

Comment: It is in a <script> element.

Comment: By the way, this is already in the head of my page: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: @Tigerman55: Is the JavaScript generated by your PHP? Which editor are you using?

Comment: @Tigerman55: Oh, you’re talking about when it’s being *sent*? Sorry, I misread the question. Okay, yep, make sure the `<meta charset="utf-8">` goes in your e-mail, too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it turns out that I just needed to delete the dash then manually type it in. My JavaScript was just something I had in the head of my page, it was not generated with PHP. I use Adobe Dreamweaver cs6. Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Tigerman55: But when you typed it back in, you got a hyphen. Not a dash. Very different. It probably looks fine, but I’d recommend you hunt down the problem anyways, just in case somebody wants to add some other character to it. Encoding is tricky. Anyways, happy to help, and congratulations on the fix. :D

Comment: How would you say to fix it fully then? I have followed your instructions yet it did not help. I have also done a lot of research and there are not many solutions out there that I can find. What would you recommend?

Comment: @Tigerman55: You’ve added `<meta charset="utf-8">` to your HTML e-mail? (Is it HTML or plain text?)

Comment: My Email is using HEREDOC syntax with PHP, generating HTML that way, I used HTML with parsed PHP variables within the HEREDOC. I used <meta charset="utf-8"> in both my HTML page where the form is and also the HTML page in which the Email is sent in the HEREDOC syntax.

Comment: @Tigerman55: Well, without seeing the code and possibly all sorts of configuration (PHP can be like that at times), try the “last resort” thing: `utf8_decode`. e.g. `echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(utf8_decode($body_part)));` or however you were outputting that before.

Comment: Ok, so just use those functions on the HTML variable where the email is stored? It is displaying right on my HTML page at least. Yeah, my code is VERY long overall, so that is why I just posted a few snippets in my question. Thanks again for helping me to find a better solution.

Comment: It turns out when I added those functions on the email variable, it converted the HTML to a string instead of HTML. It looks like a bunch of tags one after the other instead of turning into a page... What might have caused that?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your text editor / IDE is set to save files as UTF-8 with NO BOM.

Also, be sure you are using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in your page `<head>` and setting your emails up as UTF-8.